# Ionic/Cordova can't display picture taken

Tags: android, cordova, camera, ionic-framework

So I'm trying to get the camera to take a picture and display it in img tag, simple enough right ? Everything seems fine, I'm able to take a picture and the URI is printed, but I'm getting an error on $scope.$apply(). I'm running it on Android 4.4.4. Here's my code:

```
.controller("TakePictureController", function($scope, Camera) {
    $scope.getPhoto = function() {
        Camera.getPicture().then(function(imageURI) {
            $scope.src =  imageURI;
            $scope.$apply();
          console.log(imageURI);
        }, function(err) {
          console.log(err);
        });
      };
});

.factory('Camera', ['$q', function($q) {
  return {
    getPicture: function(options) {
      var q = $q.defer();
      navigator.camera.getPicture(function(result) {
        q.resolve(result);
      }, function(err) {
        q.reject(err);
      }, options);
      return q.promise;
    }
  }
}])
```

and the HTML:

```
 <ion-content class="padding">
        <button class="button button-full button-positive" ng-click="getPhoto()">
            Take pic
        </button>
        <img ng-src="{{src}}">
 </ion-content>
```

This is what I get in the console as URI:

```
file:///storage/sdcard0/Android/data/com.ionicframework.overtredingbe668924/cache/1437826221441.jpg
```

This is the error I get:

```
12    237093   error    Error: [$rootScope:inprog] $digest already in progress
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.13/$rootScope/inprog?p0=%24digest
```

I tried putting this in

```
if(!$scope.$$phase) {
   $scope.$apply();
}
```

I don't get the error anymore, but picture is not shown. Any advice ?

Comment: you don't need to trigger `$apply` since the built-in `$q` does that for you. try to debug the uri by `console.log(imageURI)`

Comment: let's troubleshoot it - https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84261/troubleshooting-ionic